# removing tablet from and array mean stack

Tags: javascript, mean-stack

Hi I was wondering if someone could help me remove tablets from a container(array) I added them to in the MEAN stack.

[image]

My backend Container Controller

```
exports.updateContainer = function (req, res) {
     console.log("container update backend controller called", req.body);
    Container.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set: req.body }, { 'new': true })
        .then( function (container) {
            console.log("container",container);
            if (container != null) {
                return res.json(container);
            }
        })
        .catch( function (err) {
            return res.json(err);
        });
```

My frond end add to container controller works, I'm having trouble with deleting them,looking at examples online i see the splice method being called a lot but I cant get it to work, say my logic is probably wrong anyway, I'm really struggling with the MEAN stack and JavaScript in general

```
 $scope.addTabletToContainer = function(tablet) {
            var container = $scope.currentContainer;

            console.log("****  container,", container);
            console.log("**** tablet to add", tablet);

            container.tablets.push(tablet);
            console.log("new tablets", container.tablets);


            containerService.updateContainer(container) 
            .success(function(data) {
               console.log("data, ",  data);

            })
            .error(function (err) {
                $location.path("./landingpage");
            });
        };

   // not working yet
        $scope.removeTabletFromContainer = function(tablet){
            var container = $scope.currentContainer;
            var index = container.tablets.indexOf(tablet);

            container.splice(index,1);

            containerService.updateContainer(container) 
            .success(function(data) {
               console.log("data, ",  data);

            })
            .error(function (err) {
                $location.path("./landingpage");
            });
        };
```

Container end points in my routes file

```
var ContainerApi = require('./api/tablet/controller/container');

api.get('/getContainers', ContainerApi.getContainers);
    api.get('/getContainer/:id', ContainerApi.getContainer);
    api.delete('/deleteContainer/:id', ContainerApi.deleteContainer);
    api.post('/createContainer', ContainerApi.createContainer);
    api.put('/updateContainer/:id', ContainerApi.updateContainer);
```

A snippet of my html

```
<ul  class="tablets" >
                    <li id="tabsincontainer" ng-repeat="tablet in currentContainer.tablets | filter:{name: query } | orderBy:orderProp" class="thumbnail">

                            <b>    Name:</b>  {{tablet.name}} , 
                            <b>    Dose:</b>  {{tablet.dose}} , 
                            <b>    Amount To Take:</b>  {{tablet.amountToTake}} , 
                            <b>    Total Amount:</b>  {{tablet.totalAmount}}

                            <button class="btn btn-xs pull-right btn-danger" ng-click="removeTabletFromContainer(tablet)">Remove</button>

                </div>
```

I get this error at the moment

```
angular.js:9937 TypeError: container.splice is not a function
    at a.$$childScopeClass.$$childScopeClass.$scope.removeTabletFromContainer (viewContainersController.js:90)
```

Comment: nevermind I got it going just noticed my mistake

i forgot  .tablets when splicing           container.splice.tablets(index,1);

Comment: I think `container.tablets` is an array, while `contianer` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to splice from container.tablets like

```
container.tablets.splice(index,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that `splice` is either not a member of `container`, or, if it is, it is not a `function`. Since `splice` is a `function` of arrays, your problem essentially is that `container` is not an array. Take a look at the definition of container:

```
var container = $scope.currentContainer;
```

`container` is not an array, since in that case you could not get the error message you have shown us, therefore you cannot call its `splice` method. Since you intend to remove from the `tablets`, let's take a look at what `tablets` are in your case. Since `tablets` is a member of `container` and has an `indexOf` and a `push` `function`, it is safe to assume that `tablets` is the array you are looking for, so you will need to call `container.tablets.splice` instead of `container.splice`.